# На сколько статичные сайты устойчивее к DDOS?

Tags: безопасность, ddos, dos-атака

Можно ли считать что статические сайты или сайты которые получают контент с API с другого сервера более устойчивы к DOS и DDOS атакам?

Изменено:
Сервер API не в счет. Вопрос был задан для того чтобы понять есть ли смысл в том чтобы подключать множество (20+) сайтов к одному API CMS системы расположенной на мощном сервере. Таким образом предполагается распределить нагрузку. Например если у вас небольшой интернет магазин то вам дорого покупать дорогой хостинг только ради устойчивости к DDOS, но если таких сайтов 100+ и хостинг соответствующий то DDOS потребует ооочень много ресурсов.

Comment: При создаёт дополнительную нагрузку на сервер

Comment: Насколько-то устойчивее. Но конкретные цифры назвать невозможно. Слишком уж вопрос абстрактный.

Comment: И особенно если они получают контент с API другого сервера. Может первый сайт и выдержит, но выдержит ли API сервер нагрузку ...

Comment: И опять же все относительно, может ваш статичный сайт расположен на канале 100МБит. А другой не статичный на 1 ГБит и при этом способен отвечать с такой скоростью и в итоге выйдет, что статичный ляжет как только ему забьют всю полосу пропускания и это будет значительно быстрее, чем на гигабитном

Comment: Сервер API не в счет. Вопрос был задан для того чтобы понять есть ли смысл в том чтобы подключать множество (20+) сайтов к одному API CMS системы расположенной на мощном сервере. Таким образом предполагается распределить нагрузку. Например если у вас небольшой интернет магазин то вам дорого покупать дорогой хостинг только ради устойчивости к DDOS, но если таких сайтов 100+ и хостинг соответствующий то DDOS потребует ооочень много ресурсов.

Comment: Защищаться от ддоса просто более мощным сервером - такая себе идея.  Лучше подумать о нормальной настройке вебсервера и фаервола. А можно попросить специализированные сервисы, например cloudflare.

Comment: Учитывая, что узкое место CMS систем именно БД, которая как я понимаю скрывается как раз на API (потому что скрипты таких сайтов только и делают что все берут из БД, другая работа это 1% ожиданий) то такое решение при DDOS атаке на один сайт сразу положит все 20+ сайтов, так как перегрузит БД и API сервер какими бы мощными они ни были

Comment: Но это может быть и не так, надо смотреть в вашем конкретном случае что за API такой. А для этого надо изучить код сайта, провести профилирование, разобраться что в вашей конкретной системе является наиболее чувствительным к DDOS. Ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно без не рассматривая вашу конкретную систему, а не условный "магазин на API CMS"

Comment: Главный смысл идеи в том чтобы увеличить количество необходимых ресурсов для DDOS на столько что DDOS атака потребует огромное количество ресурсов. Вот ссылка на расценки атак https://media.kasperskycontenthub.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/58/2017/03/09053408/ddos_economics_ru_9.png

Comment: Грубо говоря чтобы повалить сайт потребуется не 75$, а 75000$. И да, даже если кому то удастся повалить сервер и все 100 сайтов то это будет стоить того.

Comment: Повторю, без профилирования и понимания тонких мест конкретно вашего кода невозможно ответить на вопрос. Что бы знать где увеличивать мощность надо точно знать что именно потребляет и какие ресурсы. Но в любом случае если есть прослойка клиент-сайт-API_сервер то именно на плечи "сайт" ложиться отсеивание левых запросов, что бы DDOS не доходил до API сервера, потому что он обычно в таких схемах самый уязвимый

Comment: В вашей схеме одной неоптимальной строки на одном из 100 сайтов хватит для того что бы атака за $7 повалила все 100 сайтов. Задача обычно как раз обратная, как можно сильнее разделить отдельные сайты и лимитировать их по потреблению ресурсов

Comment: Отвечая на ваш вопрос: статические сайты, где web-сервер (желательно nginx) отдает с диска содержимое безусловно устойчивее динамических. А динамические сайты разделенные на собственно "сайт" и отдельно API-сервер могут быть устойчивее только в случае если первая компонента, т.е. "сайт" выполняет много ресурсоемкой работы самостоятельно, без API-сервера. Или если она например кеширует ответы API, что бы снижать количество запросов на него. Но обычно как раз API выполняет львиную долю работы, в итоге разделение как вы предлагаете только ухудшает ситуацию

Comment: А еще, когда вы сделаете API на 20+ сайтов и он начнет тормозить вам будет сложно определить какой именно сайт приводит к проблеме. Т.е. вы даже не узнаете на какой из сайтов идет ddos атака что бы отключив его спасти остальные